# Find the longest matching prefix in file?

Tags: shell, grep

For example, file `a.txt`:

```
/abc
/abc/def
/abc/xyz
/abcd
/fghi
```

Give input and expected results are:

```
/abc/dog     => /abc
/abc/def12   => /abc/def
/dog         => (NONE)
```

Is this possible using only shell commands or `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, etc. stuff?

Comment: I think that the query `/abc/dog` should return `/abc/d`.

Comment: @mrucci: I believe the desired result is that the input should match the entire line in `a.txt` rather than partial matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to somewhat reverse the idea of which is the input and use `a.txt` as the patterns to search for and what you're calling "input" (I'll call "file2") to be what is searched *in*:

```
grep -o -f a.txt file2
```

or

```
echo "/abc/dog" | grep -o -f a.txt
```

These won't output anything for "/dog", although the `echo` version will have a non-zero return code.

**Edit:**

This will more closely match your requested output:

```
while read -r line
do
    match=$(echo "$line" | grep -of a.txt)
    match=${match:-(NONE)}
    printf "%-12s => %s\n" "$line" "$match"
done < file2
```

You can force the search patterns to start at the beginning of the line like this:

```
grep -o -f <(sed 's/^/^/' a.txt) file2
```

Comment: This needs `a.txt` to be sorted descending though, but that is easily done using `sort -r`.

Comment: Oh, and this would also match `/dog/abc`, unless the patterns in `a.txt` are prefixed with `^`? (Like `^/abc`)

Comment: @Arjan: I added a way to anchor the patterns to the beginning of the line. Can you show me an example of `sort -r` being necessary?

Comment: Yup, I saw the change but cannot upvote twice ;-). `echo "/abc/def12/" | grep -o -f a.txt` should yield `/abc/def`, right? Without sorting it would show `/abc`. (At least, on a Mac it does.) Maybe it should be sorted by length, not alphabetically, but I guess it has the same effect.

Comment: @Arjan: On my Linux system, `echo "/abc/def12/" | grep -o -f a.txt` yields `/abc/def` without sorting.

Comment: Hmmm, [see my results](http://pastebin.com/TjW7gKgt). But well, the question asker will see if `echo "/abc/def12/" | grep -o -f <(sort -r a.txt)` is needed instead. (Nice answer!)

Comment: @Arjan: That's weird. I'm using `grep` 2.5.4. What locale are you using? That could possibly have an effect. I'm using `en_US.utf8`, but a few others I tried gave the same results.

Comment: `locale` gives me the following. Not sure if that helps? 
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=

Comment: No, I tried it in the C locale and it worked. I can't reproduce the `/abc` result that you see. You're using GNU `grep` on a Mac?

Comment: Yup, just the included thing. `grep --version` shows `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1 Copyright 1988, 1992-1999, 2000, 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` And no GREP specific environment variables... )I do have `COMMAND_MODE=unix2003`, maybe that matters? Using `UNSET COMMAND_MODE` makes no difference.)

Comment: @Arjan: I'm surprised it's GNU `grep` since OS X is BSD-based.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for Perl, so here's an awk solution. Minimally tested.

```
#!/bin/sh
prefixes_file=$1
shift
awk -vprefixes_file="$prefixes_file" '
BEGIN {
    while (getline <prefixes_file) { ++prefixes[$0]; }
}
{
    for (n = length; n >= 0; --n) {
        if (prefixes[substr($0,1,n)]) {
            print $0, "=>", substr($0,1,n);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (n == -1) { print $0, "=>", "(NONE)"; }
}' "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple shell script should do the job:

```
#!/bin/sh

query=$1
file=$2

for i in $(seq 1 ${#query})
do
    current_query=$(echo $query | cut -b1-$i)
    grep -q "$current_query" "$file" || break;
    longest_match=$current_query
done

echo "$longest_match"
```

You can use it like:

```
longest_match.sh '/abc/dog' a.txt
```

and it will print the longest match of the query `/abc/dog` found in the file a.txt, i.e. `/abc/d`

Comment: That could be incredibly slow.